# Click on link at the bottom of the page, page scrolls up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on my page I have a lot of items displayed. You can scroll around and view them. By clicking on an item a little tooltip appears.

I have realized that with [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/), a jQuery tooltip library. My problem is that when I scroll down and click on an item the page scrolls up again so I have to scroll down again to view the tooltip.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: is that the one clicking is href???

Comment: And what mark-up would you be using? Post a demo (that reproduces your problem) at something like [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), that we can work with.

Comment: @artwordad , if it is href then check if you have ahref=#

Comment: oh thanks for the hint, i have a href="#" on that element

Comment: i gave some sample code , can you please check that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are you using a `href="#"` on your items, you need to `return false` in your click handler, else it will fall through to the browser's default handlers, and `#` means 'go to top of the page'.

Comment: +1, but the better way is to use `event.preventDefault()`. returning false will stop all other click handlers from being fired.

Comment: @nickf agree with you , about to say the same.

Comment: how exactly do I implement that?

Comment: I removed the href="#" but the pointer that appears on hover is missing now, so I added a cursior:pointer to the css now it works. is that a solution?

Comment: @artworkad , thats should be ok , you can manage that with cursur type, if you would have given the code before , i would be the first to answer your question , i was waiting confirmation from you that you were using a href,,,anyway just kidding

Comment: I gave you an "up" on both answer and comment for your help ;)

Comment: @artworkad ,no problem ,just kidding its all just for learning

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" class="test"> hello </a>
```

the following code will make the page jump to top because of its default behavior href=#

```
$(".test").click(function() {
alert("alert")
        });
```

// event.preventDefault() will fix the default behavior of href and stops the jump to happen

```
$(".test").click(function() {
alert("alert")
event.preventDefault()
        });
```

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem without javascript, have a look at my comment in moeffju's answer

Comment: @all , i didn't copy idea from other answer , i was just waiting to get confirmation that he is using href....

Comment: @artwork , i think it should be good to keep href for SEO purposes otherwise it doesn't treat as right ahref..// iwill get you some valid reference please wait